# Setting up new Mac Mini with Big Sur. Where is iCloud Data?

Tags: icloud, big-sur

It is now several hours after setting up a new Mac Mini (M1), running Big Sur.

I have "Desktop & Documents Folders" checked in iCloud settings.

Yet, those directories do not appear to be syncing with iCloud.

Is there any way to tell if this is simply updating very slowly or if there is an actual issue with this? And if the latter, what can I try to resolve it?

For reference, there are ~64GB of iCloud documents, and they are visible from other devices.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Go to the Documents or Desktop folder and simply create/copy a new folder or a file. See if that triggers the sync on your new Mac Mini.

Comment: tried it and it says "Waiting for Update" beneath the icon.

Comment: after restarting, it no longer has that "Waiting for Update" status, but still nothing else has been populated.

Comment: On a possibly related note, the nsurlsessiond process has now received over 3GB of data since doing that, and is slowly climbing. Is that the process that is maybe updating iCloud documents? If so, then yes, it seems like this may have worked.

Comment: Well, that seemed to stop after about 3.5GB and is not updating anymore. I have since restarted because of a system update to 11.01, but nothing has populated so I don't think it worked.

Does it matter that this is Big Sur and the previous devices were on Catalina?